# Getting directory of program when called from a different application

Tags: .net

I have Program1 on my desktop. Program1 is supposed to open Program2. I have Program2 in \Folder1\Folder2.

So everything looks like this:

Program 1 = On Desktop

Program 2 = \Folder1\Folder2\Program2.exe

I'm using this code in Program1 to open Program2:

```
 Process.Start("Z:\Folder1\Folder2\Program2.exe")
```

So, once Program2 is open, it is find the path of a file that's contained in Folder1 using this code:

```
 Dim Path As String= System.IO.Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()
```

So we open Program1. Program1 opens Program2. Program2 opens a file one directory down, in Folder1.

When I execute Program2 directly, everything works. However, when I launch Program1, it opens Program2 which for whatever reason, thinks that the directory is that of Program1.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the code that from Program1 opens Program2

Comment: Edited my original post!

Comment: Use the ProcessStartInfo class to pass more detailed information to Process.Start. In particular setting the WorkingDirectory

Comment: Thanks Steve. Just bear with  me here. So Program1 is completely separate from Program2. Would me altering the code in Program1 have a different effect on the path returned when Program2 tries to locate its own path + one folder down?

Comment: Maybe `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(0)` in program 2

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, Environment.CurrentDirectory reflects the directory where the whole chain of processes started, in this case the desktop when Program1 starts.  When program2 is run independently, it works correectly because that is where the process started.

To always get Program2's directory, you should use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location from within the code in Program2.

Comment: Thanks! So I tried this:     


 Dim Path As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)


But that returns the whole path, and I don't know how to navigate one folder down. Sorry for the poor formatting of my comment. I don't know how to skip a line.

Comment: You should just be able to append the next directory level to the string you get back and then open the file from that path.